# Go equivalent of GCD serial dispatch queue

Tags: sql, go, queue, grand-central-dispatch

Is there Go equivalent of Apple's GCD serial dispatch queue?

So far I have only found a solution that is a channel of functions.

```
work := make(chan func())
```

I would have a function receive from this channel and call the received functions. The functions must be executed in FIFO order.

Is there a better method or structure to do this in Go?

*This shouldn't make a difference but I am looking to queue SQL queries to run in FIFO for this.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@OneOfOne, it was close but not quite.

I ended up making a Serial Dispatch Queue implementation in Go available [here](https://github.com/ansonl/serialqueue).

It is basically a go routine that blocks on a `channel` of type `func()` and runs the functions that are passed in order.

**Implementation:**

```
//Package serialqueue provides a serial queue for functions. 
//Queue items are processed in First In First Out (FIFO) order. 
package serialqueue

//New returns a new serial queue.
//Enqueue items like queueObj <- func() {doWork(data)}
func New() chan func() {
    //create channel of type function
    var queue = make(chan func())

    //spawn go routine to read and run functions in the channel
    go func() {
        for true {
            nextFunction := <-queue
            nextFunction()
        }
    }()

    return queue
}
```

**Usage:** (demonstrating writing to a string in the correct order)

```
//Package serialqueue provides provides tests for github.com/ansonl/serialqueue. 
package serialqueue_test

import (
    "testing"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "github.com/ansonl/serialqueue"
    )

func TestQueue(t *testing.T) {
    //Create new serial queue
    queue := serialqueue.New()

    //Number of times to loop
    var loops = 100

    //Queue output will be added here
    var queueOutput string

    //WaitGroup for determining when queue output is finished
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    //Create function to place in queue
    var printTest = func(i int) {
        queueOutput = fmt.Sprintf("%v%v",queueOutput, i)
        wg.Done()
    }

    //Add functions to queue
    var i int;
    for i=0;i<loops;i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        t:=i
        queue <- func() {printTest(t)}
    }

    //Generate correct output
    var correctOutput string
    for i=0;i<loops;i++ {
        correctOutput = fmt.Sprintf("%v%v", correctOutput, i)       
    }

    //Wait until all functions in queue are done
    wg.Wait()

    //Compare queue output with correct output
    if queueOutput != correctOutput {
        t.Errorf("Serial Queue produced %v, want %v", queueOutput, correctOutput);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, however I'm not familiar with how GCD works so I could be way off.

```
func main() {
    q := NewQueue(10) // the size is mainly so it wouldn't block, you can play with that to your liking.
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        i := i
        q <- func() { log.Println("i =", i); wg.Done() }
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(q)
}

func NewQueue(size int) (q chan func()) {
    q = make(chan func(), size)
    go func() {
        for fn := range q {
            fn()
        }
    }()
    return
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/oSFv4OUQNq)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```golang
type SerialDispatchQueue struct {
    taskQueue   chan func()
    syncChannel chan struct{}
}

func NewSerialDispatchQueue() *SerialDispatchQueue {
    m := &SerialDispatchQueue{
        taskQueue:   make(chan func()),
        syncChannel: make(chan struct{}),
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            (<-m.taskQueue)()
            m.syncChannel <- struct{}{}
        }
    }()

    return m
}

func (m *SerialDispatchQueue) Sync(f func()) {
    m.taskQueue <- f
    <-m.syncChannel
}

func (m *SerialDispatchQueue) Async(f func()) {
    m.taskQueue <- f
}
```